# Remove multiple file extensions with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a subdomain acting as an entirely new website (subdomain.domain.com = subdomain.com). I mainly use .html files but want to get rid of those extensions (instead of http://subdomain.com/file.html, I want http://subdomain.com/file ). I've used the .htaccess code below to accomplish this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

The only problem is, I also need to get rid of the .php extension of other files on the website. Most people say to duplicate the above code with .php replacing .html. I've done that; doesn't work. I've tried many other versions of the code, and still doesn't work.

Since I'm no expert at all with .htaccess, can anyone please explain how to remove both .html and .php file extensions?
Thanks in advance.

I don't believe this is a duplicate question since I haven't seen anyone else ask how to replace multiple file extensions at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rewrite rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# for adding .html extension if matching file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]

# for adding .php extension if matching file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering; it throws a 404 though

Comment: The file is in the main domain folder(not the subdomain). And your code throws the 404 regardless of what other rules are there - I deleted them all and tried it...

Comment: Also make it `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]` (or see updates)

Comment: Whatever you did to the html block works. I made those changes to the php block and it works. But they don't both work at the same time - either the html extension or the php extension is removed depending on what code block is on the bottom (I think?)

Comment: yeah they're both 404

Comment: /home2/evolutl8/public_html/theism

Comment: No, it is in /home2/evolutl8/public_html. Should I put it in /home2/evolutl8/public_html/theism?

Comment: Yes it should be placed in `/home2/evolutl8/public_html/theism` and let me rollback to original answer.

Comment: After trying a multitude of example code and suggestions from here and around the web, yours was the first/only one to work! Thank you. Both php and html files now work without extensions in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

To remove multiple file extensions, you can use the following rule in **/root/.htaccess** .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
#terminate all rewrite loops
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#1)Remove ".html" , ".php",".css" extension.
#The following rule redirects "/file.ext" to "/file" 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(html|php|css)$ $1 [L,R,NE]
#checks if "/file" .html exists, if it exits ,map "/file" to "/file.html"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
#checks if "/file" .php exists, if it exits ,map "/file" to "/file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
#checks if "/file" .css exists, if it exits ,map "/file" to "/file.css"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.css -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.css [L]
```

The rules above remove .php ,.html and .css extension. To remove more extensions you can edit this .htaccess as per your need.